# Pausing Spring Cloud StreamListener for Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

We use Spring Cloud Stream(version 3.0.7) StreamListener to consume from Google cloud PubSub subscription 'A.SUB' from topic 'A'.
We have a requirement to pause consumption from PubSub, I see below options in the order of preference, I don't have exact idea on how to achieve options 1 and 2. Can someone please share thoughts on these?

1. Add another Pubsub Topic 'B' and publish 'Pause' event message to pause or 'Resume' event message to resume, somehow stop/start poller on subscription 'A.SUB' on seeing 'pause/resume'
   Is there any way to achieve this?
2. Pause the subscription based on time window say between 12AM to 6AM? is there a way to specify some CRON expression?
3. Consume messages from 'A.SUB' and send nack between 12AM and 6AM

@StreamListener("A.SUB")
public void consume(Message message) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: StreamListener and the entire annotation-based configuration model has been deprecated. We've fully migrated to [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages) which is much simpler.

With regard to pausing, you can accomplish it with actuator and binding endpoints (e.g., stop, start, pause, resume) exposed by s-c-stream. You can get more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control).